What should be the velocity of the bucket at the top when it's moving in a vertical circle so that the water does not spill?
The exact question is this:

a cylindrical bucket filled with water is whirled around in a vertical circle of radius r. what can be the minimum speed at the top of the path if water does not fall out of the bucket?

The solution in my book says that when we take the water as the system, the normal force exerted by the bucket is zero at the top and so $mg=mv^2/r$. But I don't understand why the normal force is zero.

There are no adhesive forces acting between the bucket and the water molecules, by the time the water starts falling the bucket applies a normal force on the water molecules (from the right, say the bucket was rotating anticlockwise), and when the normal force is applied the bucket is no longer at the top but some dx distance from the top position.

This seems like a conceptual question to me.

Poor wording. Net force in the vertical direction is zero. I think that's what they meant with "Normal force"; not the usual usage of the word normal force that we use in physics.

I assume you are asking about the normal force between water and flat surface of bucket. If $mv^2/r <mg$, the water will fall so obviously the normal force is 0. If $mv^2/r =mg$, water does not fall but the normal is still 0. Only if $mv^2/r>mg$, there is some normal force.

@AlphaLife No... at the top of the circle there is always $mg$ downward and no upward force to counter it, so the net force will never be zero

@BioPhysicist you are right, my bad.

At the top of the circle, the forces acting on the water are the "normal force" $N$ and the weight force $mg$, both of which act radially inward (down). So then, in order to have circular motion, the following relation must hold:
$$\frac{mv^2}{r}=mg+N\to N=\frac{mv^2}{r}-mg$$
Therefore, if $v$ is small enough ($v<\sqrt{gr}$), we would actually require the normal force to point radially outward to maintain circular motion ($N<0$ in this case). The normal force can't do that though, and there isn't any other force that can point radially outward to help. Therefore, circular motion is no longer possible, and the water would fall. The cut off point is therefore right when $N=0$ and $v=\sqrt{gr}$.

I don't understand why normal force shld point outward... Do u mean there must be some force upward so that the water doesn't fall and that force can only be normal force since mg and mv²/r are always down at the top of the circle? If my understanding is right then yea that can't be possible in this case since normal force is also downward... So then how does it becoming zero help the water from not falling down?

@android The normal force becoming $0$ is the cut off point for when circular motion is no longer possible, since if you lower the speed further from there you will not be able to produce the correct amount of centripetal force because $N$ cannot point outward.

so ur saying that, we can keep lowering the normal to achieve lower velocities, and this holds true only till normal=0, and thats when the velocity is the least and beyond this, circular motion is not possible... am i rite?

@android I would say you keep lowering the speed until $N=0$ at the top. But yes

i have another doubt regarding skidding, slipping in circular motion... i saw many answers but i still couldnt understand so please provide your thoughts on that question if possible too
